# Difference of DialContext KeepAlive and Transport IdleTimeout of go http.Client

Tags: go, httpclient

```
client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                KeepAlive: 5 * time.Second,
            }).DialContext,
            IdleConnTimeout: 3 * time.Second,
        },
    }
```

What's the difference between KeepAlive and IdleConnTimeout?

Which of them exactly does what?

Comment: when asking api specific questions like this you should include a link to the docs after reading them to tell us you have the baseline info

Comment: Yes, both of those are described in their documentation. What parts don’t you understand exactly?

Comment: KeepAlive: specifies the keep-alive period for an active network connection. ___ IdleConnTimeout: is the maximum amount of time an idle (keep-alive) connection will remain idle before closing itself.___
     
Still confused getting the difference.

Comment: They are completely unrelated, which is why this is a confusing question.  `KeepAlive` is the TCP keepalive interval, `IdleConnTimeout` is how long the transport keeps an unused idle http connection.

Comment: Maybe that was what confused me. And completely answered my question. Wasn't clear that one is TCP and the other HTTP. Thanks

Comment: @Subby: `KeepAlive` is a field on the `net.Dialer` struct in the `net` package, and not part of the `http` package. The `net` package knows nothing of the `http` package or protocol.

Comment: At least there is a comment in the documentation that clarifies this. https://github.com/golang/go/commit/cbce223da02bb198b9984c161c6cd6291a80b3d9

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.13.8/src/net/dial.go#L72

> KeepAlive specifies the interval between keep-alive probes for an active network connection. If zero, keep-alive probes are sent with a default value (currently 15 seconds), if supported by the protocol and operating system. Network protocols or operating systems that do not support keep-alives ignore this field. If negative, keep-alive probes are disabled.

So, if you set the `KeepAlive` greater than 0, it will represent the time elapsed from the next probe in order to understand if the network connection is still active.

From the other side, the `IdleConnTimeout`:
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.13.8/src/net/dial.go#L72

> IdleConnTimeout is the maximum amount of time an idle (keep-alive) connection will remain idle before closing itself. Zero means no limit.

So, if you set an `IdleConnTimeout` greater than 0, it represents the time that the connection is still open.